# Query multiple tables at once based on common table name in Oracle through SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to fetch data from all the tables based on common table name pattern every week.Basically my requirement is to merge all the data to form a single lookup table.

**Example:**

Table Names:

```
Department_20190101
Department_20190109
Department_20190122
Department_20190129
```

I have to fetch data from all the tables and have to create a single lookup table. Is there a simple way to do this other than by going through iteration in PL/SQL by getting the table names with the help of ALL_TABLES

Note:The Date part is not consistent.If i can achieve this requirement once then i can easily start inserting the data from the new table to the existing lookup(n+1)

Please share your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very long list of tables, or you requirement is to aggergate the results from all tables e.g. starting with `Department_` followed by a certain date or range of dates, then you might need dynamic SQL for this.  For the exact example you did show in your question, a CTE with a union query might work:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM Department_20190101 UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Department_20190109 UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Department_20190122 UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Department_20190129
)
```

And then use the CTE as:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

This assumes that all tables have identical structures.  Also, as a side note, if this be the case, you might want to consider just having a single table with a date column to differentiate between the otherwise common data.

Comment: I would also add partitioning to the table, assuming the OP's db is licensed for it

Answer (score 0):

Check here:  [Execute For Each Table in PLSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142696/execute-for-each-table-in-plsql)  there is nice example to resolve Your problem using pl/sql (pl/sql help You dinamicly grow up sql-query) .